# Django-tables2 and Django-filters: Filtering list of dicts

Tags: django, django-filter, django-tables2

I have a table, that I made from 3 different models. And I want to filter them. But the problem is - all examples, that i've found - was about queryset and have only one model.

```
dict = [
    {'name': Model1.objects.get(id=1), 'adress': Model2.objects.get(id=Model1.objects.get(id=1))}, 
    {'name': Model1.objects.get(id=2),},
    ...
]
filter=FilterSet(queryset=???)
```

The point is - data from another models I got from Model1. But I can't build table on this model, because it don't have foreign keys to other 2 models.

Other words

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.Charfield()
    field2 = models.Charfield()

class Model2(models.Model):
    field3 = models.Charfield()
    field4 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
...
```

Any suggestions? Because I don't think that making another model is a good solution.

Comment: From the [django-filter github description](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter): "A generic system for filtering Django QuerySets based on user selections"

If you want to use such a custom solution, be prepared to write some custom code too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ForeignKey` to create a queryset that combines both models.  Assume your models look like this (I have renamed your FK field for clarity):

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.Charfield()
    field2 = models.Charfield()

class Model2(models.Model):
    field3 = models.Charfield()
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, related_name='model2s')
```

Say you wanted to search through all `Model2`s that had a `field3` of 'foo' and were connected to a `Model1` with a `field1` of `bar`.  You would do this like so:

```
queryset = Model2.objects.filter(field3='foo', model1__field1='bar')
```

You could start from `Model1` too, using the `related_name` field that is automagically created by Django.  (There is a default way Django will name these if you don't include a name in the `ForeignKey`, but it's always best to be explicit.)

This will return any `Model1` that has a `field1` of 'bar' and is connected to *any* `Model2` with a `field3` of 'foo'.

```
queryset = Model1.objects.filter(field1='bar', model2s__field3='foo')
```

Comment: Thanks, just what i wanted