# How to filter django-tables2 after populating it with list of dicts rather than a query set?

Tags: python, mongodb, django-filter, django-tables2

I have a list of dicts that I fetch from MongoDB.  Then I populate django-tables2 table in **views.py** and render it in my template **index.html**

In **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .tables import generateTable
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig

import pymongo
import pandas as pd
import json

client = pymongo.MongoClient("<mongodb url>")
db = client["stocks"]
col = db["company_stocks"]
the_rows = col.find({}, {'_id': False})

pandas_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(the_rows), columns=['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Name'])

json_fomatted = pandas_dataframe.to_json(orient='records')

data = []
data = json.loads(json_fomatted)

def index(request):
    table = generateTable(data)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)

    context = {'stocks_table': table }

    return render(request, "home_app/index.html", context)
```

**tables.py**

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Stocks

class generateTable(tables.Table):
    Date = tables.Column()
    Open = tables.Column()
    High = tables.Column()
    Low = tables.Column()
    Close = tables.Column()
    Volume = tables.Column()
    Name = tables.Column()
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', home_app.views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^home$', home_app.views.index, name='home'),
]
```

**index.html**

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% render_table stocks_table 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html' %}
```

[Result is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxnvx.png)

Now I am trying to filter the table with django-filter but with not luck

What I found was how to filter data that had been populated with queryset rather than list of dicts

My attempt at filtering:

**views.py**

```
...
from .models import Stocks
...

def index(request):
    table = generateTable(data)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)

    #with this line
    myFilter = stockFilter(request.GET, queryset=Stocks.objects.all())

    context = {'stocks_table': table, 'myFilter': myFilter }

    return render(request, "home_app/index.html", context)
```

**filters.py**

```
import django_filters

from .models import Stocks

class stockFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Stocks
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Stocks(models.Model):
    open = models.IntegerField(
        max_length = 128)
    high = models.IntegerField(
        max_length = 128)
    low = models.IntegerField(
        max_length = 128)
    close = models.IntegerField(
        max_length = 128)
    volume = models.IntegerField(
        max_length = 128)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length = 128)
```

**index.html**

```
<form method="GET">
   {{ myFilter.form }}
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% render_table stocks_table 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html' %}
```

Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9oGV.png)

And after [filtering...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1ZkB.png)

I think the problem is the fact that my tables are populated with a list rather than a queryset.

Is there a better way of filtering django-tables2?

Any help is much appreciated!

I found a [similar question posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671578/django-tables2-and-django-filters-filtering-list-of-dicts) but it uses multiple models for its tables

Comment: You need to apply the stockFilter to the table data in the View. Try changing the myFilter line in views.py to `myFilter = stockFilter(request.GET, data=table)`.

Comment: @Ben I appreciate the help but I'm now getting the error:" __init__() got multiple values for argument 'data'"

I think since my stockFilter class uses the model Stock from model.py I cannot filter the table by simply setting data to table (which doesn't use Stocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was after getting the desired documents from *mongo*, I created a model object *Stocks* and appended that to a list and simply bulk_create(*created list*)

**views.py**

```
the_rows = col.find({}, {'_id': False})

json_data = list(the_rows)
    
obj_list = []
for data in json_data:
    _open = round(float(data['Open']), 2)
    _high = round(float(data['High']), 2)
    _low = round(float(data['Low']), 2)
    _close = round(float(data['Close']), 2)

    obj = Stocks(name=data['Name'], date=data['Date'], open=_open, high=_high, low=_low, close=_close, volume=data['Volume'])

    obj_list.append(obj)

Stocks.objects.bulk_create(obj_list)
```

**tables.py** is based off of **models.py**

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Stocks

class generateTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Stocks;
        template = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html';
```

Then to create the table and filter, I followed steps I found [here](https://community.simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/t/integrating-django-filters-with-django-tables/699/2)

**views.py**

```
qs = Stocks.objects.all()

myFilter = stockFilter(request.GET, queryset=qs)

table = generateTable(myFilter.qs)
RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 30}).configure(table)

return render(request, "home_app/index.html", { 'stocks_table': table, 'myFilter': myFilter })
```

And finally the template **index.html**

```
{% block content %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="filter_column">
        <form>
            {{myFilter.form}}
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="table_column">
        {% render_table stocks_table %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y16Nn.png)